# How to test both Python and C++ in one .travis.yml without running the C++ multiple times?

Tags: python, c++, travis-ci

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/538 doesn't seem to really help.  I have this .travis.yml for libais:

```
language: python

python:
  - "2.7"
  - "3.4"

before_install:
  - sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
  - sudo apt-get update -qq

install:
  - sudo apt-get install -qq gcc-4.8 g++-4.8
  - CC=g++-4.8 python setup.py install

script:
  - python setup.py test
  - (cd src && CC=gcc-4.8 CXX=g++-4.8 make -f Makefile-custom test)
```

The last line of the script triggers the c++ testing.

It's great that it runs the libais gunit C++ tests, but sadly, they get run 2x.  Once for each python version.  I'd prefer not to add the additional load to travis-ci.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Dominic's answer, I looked at http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/ and found TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION.  So no need to fiddle with any files.

```
script:
  - python setup.py test
  - if [[ $TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION == '3.4' ]]; then (cd src && CC=gcc-4.8 CXX=g++-4.8 make -f Makefile-custom test); fi
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick idea: maybe you could do a check for the existence of a file before deciding to run your C++ tests?

E.g.

```
- [[ -f $FILE ]] || (cd src && CC=gcc-4.8 CXX=g++-4.8 make -f Makefile-custom test)
```

The file to check for could be for example the report of your C++ unit tests. If it's already there, don't run them a second time.

Comment: Great idea.  I could touch a file from python that gives the python version and then only test for one python version.