# Multiple Language in a single .travis.yml file

Tags: github, travis-ci

I am creating project with 5 languages together and I need to set up ***Travis CI*** to work for all languages. So, that collaboration becomes easy. But I am unable to figure out how to do so. I have tried every possible way I can think. One of them is

```
language:
  - python
  - cpp
  - java

python:
  - "3.3"
  - "3.4"
  - "3.5"
  - "3.5-dev" # 3.5 development branch
  - "nightly" # currently points to 3.6-dev

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
  - openjdk7

before_install:
  - wget https://googletest.googlecode.com/files/gtest-1.7.0.zip
  - unzip gtest-1.7.0.zip
  - cd gtest-1.7.0/
  - ./configure --prefix=$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR --with-pthreads=no
  - make
  - mkdir $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/include/
  - cp -r include/gtest $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/include
  - mkdir $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/lib/
  - cp lib/.libs/* $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/lib/
  - cd ..
  - export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/include:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
  - export LIBRARY_PATH=$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH
  - export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  - cd cpp
  - cd java
  - pip install coverage
  - cd python

# command to run tests
script:
  - nosetests -v --with-coverage
  - ant test
  - make googletest
```

Please help me by suggesting a way to overcome it.

Another reference [C++ and Python in one travis.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30404594/how-to-test-both-python-and-c-in-one-travis-yml-without-running-the-c-multi).
Thanks.

I am still unable to get this right. Can someone please give me a code snippet for atleast 4 languages C++, Java, Python and Ruby. I will be obliged.

Comment: Make a build matrix with each cell representing a different language or install the language packages manually

Comment: Sir can you please provide any links and code snippets. It will be great help for me. And thank you for precious advice.

Comment: [Build matrix](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#Build-Matrix), [APT plugin](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/installing-dependencies/#Installing-Packages-with-the-APT-Addon) ([example](https://github.com/nabijaczleweli/cpp-localiser/blob/master/.travis.yml))

Comment: May be language : generic option would help me. If someone can give example it will help me a lot.